# Laravel-dompdf slow generate pdf

Tags: laravel, pdf-generation, dompdf

I use laravel-dompdf to generate pdf from view HTML. I dont know why so much time need to make pdf (5 min).

HTML tags look not bad. I dont know where is problem. 
Someone help me?
[This link](http://pastebin.com/QEK5cTs5) - view HTML
This code get date from DB and call stream pdf

```
public function getPdf()
    {
        $this->start = Input::get('start');
        $this->end = Input::get('end');    

        $users = Users::all();
        $user_count = count($users);

        $screens = GaScreen::select(array('screen_name',
                DB::raw('SUM(display) as `display`'),
                DB::raw('SUM(drop_offs) as `drop_offs`')
                ))
                ->whereBetween('day', array($this->start, $this->end))
                ->groupBy('screen_name')->orderBy('display', 'DESC')->get();

        $screen_sum = GaScreen::whereBetween('day', array($this->start, $this->end))->sum('display');
        $recences = GaRecency::select(array('count_of_day',
                DB::raw('SUM(users) as `users`')
                ))
                ->groupBy('count_of_day')->orderBy('users', 'DESC')->get();

        $session_duration = GaSession::select(array('section',
                DB::raw('SUM(sessions) as `sessions`')
                ))
                ->whereBetween('day', array($this->start, $this->end))
                ->groupBy('section_id')->orderBy('section_id', 'ASC')->get();

        $app = new GaApp;
        $app->visits = GaApp::whereBetween('day', array($this->start, $this->end))->sum('visits');
        $app->uniq_users = GaApp::whereBetween('day', array($this->start, $this->end))->sum('uniq_users');
        $app->all_users = GaApp::whereBetween('day', array($this->start, $this->end))->sum('all_users');
        $app->avg_time = GaApp::whereBetween('day', array($this->start, $this->end))->sum('avg_time')/60;
        $app->precent_new_users = GaApp::whereBetween('day', array($this->start, $this->end))->sum('precent_new_users');
        $app->new_users = GaApp::whereBetween('day', array($this->start, $this->end))->sum('new_users');

        $network = GaApp::select(array('service',
                DB::raw('SUM(visits) as `visits`')
                ))
                ->whereBetween('day', array($this->start, $this->end))
                ->groupBy('service')->orderBy('visits', 'DESC')->get();

        $promotions = Promotion::with('shop')->get()->values()->toArray();

        //echo "<pre>" . print_r( $screen_sum, true ) . "</pre><br />";die(); 
        $shops = Shop::active()->with('industry')->orderBy('fullname')->get();

        $search = GaSearch::select(array('search_key','typable',
                DB::raw('SUM(count) as `count`'),
                ))
                ->whereBetween('day', array($this->start, $this->end))
                ->groupBy('search_key')->orderBy('count', 'DESC')->get();

        $os = GaOs::select(array('os','phone_name','os_version',
                DB::raw('SUM(users) as `users`'),
                ))
                ->where('phone_name' ,'!=', '')
                ->whereBetween('day', array($this->start, $this->end))
                ->groupBy('phone_name')->orderBy('users', 'DESC')->get();

       $pdf = PDF::loadView('ga.raport-pdf', ['screens' => $screens, 'screen_sum' => $screen_sum,'app' => $app, 
                                              'user_count' => $user_count, 'os' => $os, 'recences' => $recences,
                                              'promotions' => $promotions, 'session_duration' => $session_duration,
                                              'search' => $search, 'network' => $network,
                                              'users' => $users, 'start' => $this->start, 'end' => $this->end,
                                              'shops' => $shops]);

       return $pdf->stream(Str::slug(date('Y-m-d-H:i:s').'-raport').'.pdf');
    }
```

Comment: How long does the page take to load if you just view the HTML? How much data are you processing? The HTML itself doesn't look too complicated, but if the number of records processed is large it could affect the speed of HTML generation and PDF rendering.

Comment: Loading only view HTML lasts few seconds. Generate PDF from HTML lasts long time. I dont use so much data. Example: $promotions ~30 rows, $users ~100... I use foreach in HTML view. This foreach work very slow.

Comment: So if you load the view with the data it's only a few seconds, but then rendering that view with dompdf takes a longer time? Or does generating the HTML take a long time as well?

Comment: Yes rendering view with dompdf takes long time.

Comment: Don't suppose you can post the generated HTML? Could be the tables giving dompdf a problem. Or something about the CSS.